# Does anyone know how to fix this table?table is too big, not very good looking and

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Fundamental Options of the Channel Setup Screen } 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{l c c c} 
\hline\hline 
& \textbf{Impact Hammer} &\textbf{Accelerometer} 
\\ [0.5ex]
\hline 
&Input1 &Input2,...,16 \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Physical Channel ID}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&On &On \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{On/Off}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline
&Yes&No \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Reference}}  \\[-1ex]
\hline
&Vibration &Vibration \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Channel Group ID}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&Impact &Sensor \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Point}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&-Z &+X,+Y,+Z \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Direction}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline  
&ICP &ICP \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Input Mode}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&Single Ended &Single Ended \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Coupling}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&Force &Acceleration \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Measured Quantity}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&mV &mV \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Electrical Unit}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&Variable$^1$  &Variable$^2$ \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Actual Sensitivity}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&086C03 &356A03 \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Transducer Type}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&PCB &PCB \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Transducer Manufacturer}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&$20725$ &Variable$^3$ \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Serial Number}}   \\[-1ex]
\hline 
&Variable$^4$ &Variable$^5$ \\[-1ex]
\raisebox{1ex}{\textbf{Range}}   \\[-1ex]
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:PPer}
\\
\footnotesize {$^1$ will be different corresponding to different tip table3.1}\\

\end{table}
```

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete, compilable and small document, which we can test as it is. Also your table has bunch of errors: `\[-1x]` probably should be `\\[-1ex]` ...

Comment: i do not have any error in overleaf but it does not look very well

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of all the `\raisebox{1ex}` commands?

Answer (score 3):

The following might help get you started. I have removed all occurences of `\raisebox`,`\textbf` and `\hline`. Instead, I have added a few horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package.

Side note: The superscript numbers in the lower third of the table look like tablenotes. If that's the case, you might be interested in the `threepattable` package. I also suggest using the usual `\label` `\ref` mechanism instead of the manual reference to table 3.1.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Fundamental Options of the Channel Setup Screen}
    \label{tab:PPer} 
    \centering 
    \begin{tabular}{l l l} 
    \toprule 
                             & Impact Hammer & Accelerometer  \\
    \midrule
    Physical Channel ID      & Input1        & Input2,...,16 \\
    On/Off                   & On            & On \\
    Reference                & Yes           & No \\
    Channel Group ID         & Vibration     & Vibration \\
    Point                    & Impact        & Sensor \\
    Direction                & -Z            & +X,+Y,+Z \\
    Input Mode               & ICP           & ICP \\
    Coupling                 & Single Ended  & Single Ended \\
    Measured Quantity        & Force         & Acceleration \\
    Electrical Unit          & mV            & mV \\
    Actual Sensitivity       & Variable$^1$  & Variable$^2$ \\
    Transducer Type          & 086C03        & 356A03 \\
    Transducer Manufacturer  & PCB           & PCB \\
    Serial Number            & $20725$       & Variable$^3$ \\
    Range                    & Variable$^4$  & Variable$^5$ \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{$^1$ will be different corresponding to different tip table3.1}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

---

With `threeparttable` for the tablenotes and `\addlinespace` as a guide to the eye:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering 
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Fundamental Options of the Channel Setup Screen}
    \label{tab:PPer} 
    \begin{tabular}{l l l} 
    \toprule 
                             & Impact Hammer      & Accelerometer     \\
    \midrule
    Physical Channel ID      & Input1             & Input2,...,16     \\
    On/Off                   & On                 & On                \\
    Reference                & Yes                & No                \\
    Channel Group ID         & Vibration          & Vibration         \\
    Point                    & Impact             & Sensor            \\ \addlinespace
    Direction                & -Z                 & +X,+Y,+Z          \\
    Input Mode               & ICP                & ICP               \\
    Coupling                 & Single Ended       & Single Ended      \\
    Measured Quantity        & Force              & Acceleration      \\
    Electrical Unit          & mV                 & mV                \\ \addlinespace
    Actual Sensitivity       & Variable\tnote{1}  & Variable\tnote{2} \\
    Transducer Type          & 086C03             & 356A03            \\
    Transducer Manufacturer  & PCB                & PCB               \\
    Serial Number            & 20725              & Variable\tnote{3} \\
    Range                    & Variable\tnote{4}  & Variable\tnote{5} \\
    \midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[1]  will be different corresponding to different tip \ref{...}
    \item[2] will be different corresponding to different direction and type of accelerometer.
    \item[3] description text here
    \item[4]
    \item[6]
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: now it's better, Thanks a lot. \label and \ref are very good idea.

Comment: +1. A minor comment: Since the table has 15 data rows, I might be tempted to insert `\addlinespace` directives after rows 5 and 10 in order to provide a touch of visual grouping.

Comment: is there any way to add line in order to separate each row? except \hline because generate different (darker and lighter) line.

Comment: when i add \multicolumn{3}{l}{$^2$ will be different corresponding to different direction and type of accelerometer.}\\ corresponding to num 2 explanation the table shape will not proper anymore! like adding one vertical line at the rightest part of the table. i do not know why

Comment: @user224189: I have updated my answer in order to show you how you can use the `threeparttable` package for your table notes. I have also incorporated Mico's suggestion of using `\addlinespace` in order to guide the eye. Personally, I would recommend against adding more horizontal lines as they will not increase the readability of the table but make it less visually appealing.

Comment: now it's very nice. thanks for your help.